# urldecode() not decoding the + sign

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on a PayPal payment system, I wanna send 2 values in the custom field. Therefor I used the urlencode(json_encode()) functionality. An example of how it looks without urlencoding.

```
$customData = array();
$customData['invoiceID'] = $invoiceID;
$customData['username'] = urlencode($_GET['username']);

$p->add_field('custom', urlencode(json_encode($customData)));
```

Output is:

```
%7B%22invoiceID%22%3A108674%2C%22username%22%3A%22Just%2Btesting%22%7D
```

Desired output when urldecoding and jsondecoding:

```
{"invoiceID":108674,"username":"Just testing"}
```

But it's giving me this after urldecoding and jsondecoding:

```
{"invoiceID":108674,"username":"Just+testing"}
```

The workaround for this issue is to urldecode the username itself as well once again. But why do I have to double urldecode just to get the value that I urlencoded with just one time running this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are applying two times `urlencode()` to data so you need to apply two times `urldecode()` or remove one of them.

Comment: No that's the thing, I am not doing that

Comment: lets look like your code line by line;
`$customData['username'] = urlencode('just testing');`
result will be just+testing right?

`$p->add_field('custom', urlencode(json_encode($customData)));`
so after this one you are using to `urlencode(json_encode('just+testing'))` and this is look like to me 2nd time

Comment: Okay that was one of the most stupid things ever, that totally fixed it >.>

Answer (score 0):

I think the "custom" field is used to identify your request on the other end, correct? So, that field is for your use and not for paypal. I think it's a good idea to encode it. But, if you want it to survive paypals back end you might want to use base64encode and base64decode.